# showing vertex labels inside vertexes only

Tags: r, igraph

I have this data frame:

dput(df2)

```
structure(list(Receiver = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Australia", 
"United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States of America"
), class = "factor"), Sender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "United States of America", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Receiver", 
"Sender"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to draw and igraph as this:

```
library(igraph)
g<-graph.data.frame(df2)
plot(g, layout = layout.kamada.kawai,  vertex.label = V(g)$name,  
     vertex.label.color= "red",  edge.arrow.size=0.8,  
      edge.curved=T, edge.label.color="white",                              
      edge.label.cex=0.8,vertex.shape="circle",edge.color="pink",
      vertex.color="lightblue", asp=0, margin=0)
```

I would like to show vertex lables inside the verexes, without increasing the size of the vertexes. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this before the call plot:

```
  V(g)$label.cex <- 0.5
```

But why not to use a shortcut of the names?

```
 V(g)$name<-c('USA','UK','UAE','Aus')
```

[image]

```
dat <- structure(list(Receiver = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Australia", 
                                                                  "United Arab \nEmirates", "United \nKingdom", "United \nStates of \nAmerica"
), class = "factor"), Sender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "United \nStates of \nAmerica", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Receiver", 
                                                                                                                                "Sender"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")


library(igraph)
g<-graph.data.frame(dat)
V(g)$label.cex <- 0.6
plot(g, layout = layout.kamada.kawai,  vertex.label = V(g)$name,  
     vertex.label.color= "red",  edge.arrow.size=0.8,  
     edge.curved=T, edge.label.color="white",                              
     edge.label.cex=0.8,vertex.shape="circle",edge.color="pink",
     vertex.color="lightblue", asp=0, margin=0)
```

Comment: both of these options will not work. Since cex only changes the font size. I would like to be able to do a new line after certain characters.

Comment: @user1471980 why not to mention this in your question? How I will guess it?

Comment: @user1471980 I am still wiating for more details why this will not work. I tested the 2 options and for me they answer the question.

Comment: I need to find a way to print the V(g)$Names within the circle. They cannot go out side of the vertex.

Comment: @user1471980 you c'ant get better I think with the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help.

```
# size the network nodes based on their centrality
deg = igraph::degree(graph = g, v = V(g), mode = "all", loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE);
igraph::V(g)$size = deg*3;

# set the label size based on the node size
igraph::V(g)$label.cex = igraph::V(g)$size/max(igraph::V(g)$size);
```